# why doesn't my extends statement work?

Tags: java, extends

For some reason, the `extends` statement at the top of my class produces an error in Eclipse. The error says

> "Multiple markers at this line 
>  
>   The import Employee cannot be resolved 
>   Breakpoint:Manager"

The error is on the first line of this block of code:

```
public class Manager extends Employee 
{
    private String title;
    private double bonus;

    public Manager()
    {
        title = "";
        bonus = 0;
    }

    public Manager(String title, double bonus, 
            String n, String ssNum, double s, maritalStatus mStatus)
    {
        super(n, ssNum, s, mStatus);
        this.title = title;
        this.bonus = bonus;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + "\nTitle: " + title + "\nBonus ($): " + bonus; 
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is the `Employee` class defined? Is it in the same package as your class, or is it in another package?

Comment: yes, it seems to be in the same default package in my eclipse program

Comment: Try cleaning your project in Eclipse (forget where the menu option is, I think it's under `Project`), and refreshing the workspace if not. If neither of those work - are `Employee.java` and `Manager.java` in the same folder? Did you try an `import Employee;'?

Comment: I'd use the Organize Imports menu under the Source menu.  That will remove any unnecessary imports and will find Employee for you and add an import for it.  The Employee class will need to have the right visibility.

Answer (score 0):

The "breakpoint" message is there because you have a breakpoint defined on that line - irrelevant to this issue (right-click on the column on the left-hand edge of the line and un-check "Toggle Breakpoint")

The "import Employee" may be solved by deleting the relevant import line entirely and hovering over the dotted red under-line of the error and clicking on the "import ...Employee" quick fix option.

Comment: Eclipse automatically added an import statement, "import Employee.maritalStatus;" and I saw the "The import Employee cannot be resolved" error on that line. Then I removed the statement because I didn't write it, and the error simply got moved to the extends statement, which is when I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you try to import something that is already in the same package. Moreover, you use the default package, which is not recomended.

Try moving both of your classes to another package and remove the import.

I hope it helps.